# Strange redirects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on an app made with AngularJS using Firebase logging system. I have a strange redirect when I try to login - it redirects to the register page for some reason no matter if the logging is successful or not. If the alert shoud show up it shows up at the register page.
Tried deleting the route to register page - no luck. Tried deleting actions that happened when OnAuthStateChanged triggered - still redirects. Tried debugging the app - it seems that the function

```
for (var i = 0; i < eventFnsLength; i++) {
  if (!event.isImmediatePropagationStopped()) {
    handlerWrapper(element, event, eventFns[i]);
  }
}
```

in angular.js in line 3532 causes that but I have no idea how to make it stop.

SignInCtrl.js

```
angular.module('szybkiePisanie')
.controller('SignInCtrl', ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", function ($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
    $scope.SignIn = function (event) {
        if ($scope.user.email != undefined) var email = $scope.user.email; else { alert("Wpisz adres e-mail"); return; }
        if ($scope.user.password != undefined) var password = $scope.user.password; else { alert("Wpisz hasło"); return; }
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {                
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

            if (email.length < 4) {
                alert('Proszę wpisać adres email.');
                return;
            }
            if (password.length < 4) {
                alert('Proszę wpisać hasło.');
                return;
            }
            ;
            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                alert('Błędne hasło.');
            }
            else if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                alert('Nieprawidłowy adres email');
            }
            else if (errorCode === 'auth/user-disabled') {
                alert('Użytkownik zablokowany');
            }
            else if (errorCode) {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
        })
    }
}]);
```

RegisterCtrl.js

```
angular.module('szybkiePisanie')
.controller('RegisterCtrl', ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", function ($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
    $scope.Register = function (event) {
        if ($scope.user.email != undefined) var email = $scope.user.email; else { alert("Wpisz mejl"); return; }
        if ($scope.user.password != undefined) var password = $scope.user.password; else { alert("Wpisz haslo"); return; }
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

            if (email.length < 4) {
                alert('Please enter an email address.');
                return;
            }
            if (password.length < 4) {
                alert('Please enter a password.');
                return;
            }
        })
    }
}]);
```

script.js(routing)

```
angular.module('szybkiePisanie', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])
.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'Home/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })

            .when('/practice', {
                templateUrl: 'Practice/practice.html',
                controller: 'PracticeCtrl'
            })

            .when('/signin', {
                templateUrl: 'SignIn/signin.html',
                controller: 'SignInCtrl'
            })

            .when('/profile', {
                templateUrl: 'Profile/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
            })

            .when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'Register/register.html',
                controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            })
    }]);
```

Edit:
Redirect is not only caused by Singing in. In fact any button or dropdown will cause my app to redirect from '/singin' to '/register'. Strange.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle where we can reproduce this ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/6E8u51cQRboz6yrJv9EU?p=preview

Comment: I can't reproduce any redirect. Since I don't have any valid email-pass I tried a valid email with any password text and I got only one request that causes 400 error because, well, authentication failed. But I don't see any redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what what causing the redirect. I haven't ended the 'a' tag on my site and the rest of the site was acting as a link.

Answer (score 0):

You only specified two possible routes: `/signin` and `/register`. Thus the router will only support one of these routes and you will end up being redirected to one of them. The problem might be that you have not defined the route for the logged in state which should be kind of the default route. As far as I know when using angular router you need to define every route you want to support.

```
    angular.module('szybkiePisanie', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])
    .config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/signin', {
                    templateUrl: 'SignIn/signin.html',
                    controller: 'SignInCtrl'
                })

                .when('/register', {
                    templateUrl: 'Register/register.html',
                    controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
                })

                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'Home/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                })

                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }]);
```

Comment: I actually have that in my code - i just didn't include it in here for clarity. I will edit it though.